# iOS: Scrollview showing pagecontrol out of screen

Tags: iphone, scrollview, pagecontrol

I need to display many images in uiscrollview with uipagecontrol showing indication of current image. I have implemented all the features and everything is working fine. But server is returning around 40-45 images at once, then uipagecontrol goes out of the screen. Below is my screen shot. Please help me in this, how should i control that.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have many dots then its not advisable to use pagecontrol.But if you want to proceed with it then you can use the below code which scales pagecontrol

```
yourpagecontroll.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
```

You can change the value according to your requirement.